# How do I create a recursive anagram tool which prints every possible combination of a string of letters, including prefixes?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, combinations

I've made an anagram method to create all the possible combinations of a word, but I'd like to be able to check every letter combination.

For example: eastern would produce other variations such as earnest, but I'd also like it to produce variations such as east and eat and ate.

I already have a working dictionary checking whether the combinations are in the dictionary.

```
public void printAnagrams(String prefix, String word)
{
    if(word.length() == 1) {
        if (words.contains(prefix+word))
            System.out.println(prefix + word);
    }
    else    
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            String current = word.substring(i, i + 1);
            String before = word.substring(0, i);
            String after = word.substring(i+1);
            printAnagrams(prefix + current, before + after);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick google search (Java print all combinations) found numerous Java solutions to this problem.  In particular, the first result was just 2 functions, total of 5 or 6 lines of code, that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a set of `chars` [can be a `char[]`] and "guess" which is the next letter, and append it to an intermediate `sol` StringBuilder, which holds the current substring. Invoke the algorithm recursively to find out next chars of the solution.

Have an index `i` to indicate which chars can be used [all chars "right" to `i`].

At each iteration - print the resulting string, even if you did not the maximal length.

Pseudo code:

```
findPermutations(chars,i,sol):
   print sol
   if (chars.length == i):
       return
   for each j in range(j,chars.length):
       sol.append(chars[i+1])
       swap(chars,i,j) //we cannot use chars[j] anymore.
       findPermutations(chars,j+1,sol)
       swap(chars,i,j) //clean up environment
       sol.removeLast()
```

Notes:

1. This solution assumes `chars` is a set, so if a certain char appears more then once - you are going to have duplicates, but it will still work [generate all possibilities]
2. A word about complexity: There are exponential number of possibilities, and you want all of them. So, if you try to invoke this method [and actually any algorithm to do it] with more then 20 chars, you are expected to finish generating all possibilities in ~200 years